# Inheritence Java super.print() not returning values

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, casting

My code won't print out the Paid, Current hours and Total Sales for the commission and I think it might have something to do with the inheritance but I'm not sure. I casted them in another class but I think the problem is here because there was no issues with the casting of my other classes. All of the values return in the program besides those 3 for Commission. The Pay and current hours update for hourly which Commission is inherited from but it doesn't work in the Commission class.

```
//StaffMember Class
public abstract class StaffMember {
protected String name, address, number;

public StaffMember(String name, String address, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.number = number;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Name: " +name + "\nAddress: " +address + "\nPhone: " +number;
}

public abstract double pay();
}

//Employee Class
public class Employee extends StaffMember{
    private String rsiNumber;
    protected double payRate;

public Employee(String rsiNumber, double payRate, String name, String address, String number) {
    super(name, address, number);
    this.rsiNumber = rsiNumber;
    this.payRate = payRate;
}

public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "\nRSI Number: " +rsiNumber + String.format("\nPaid: €%,.2f" ,pay());
}

public double pay(){
    return payRate;
}
}


//Hourly Class
public class Hourly extends Employee{
    private int hours;

public Hourly(String rsiNumber, double payRate, String name, String address, String number) {
    super(rsiNumber, payRate, name, address, number);
    this.hours = 0;
}

public void addHours(int hours){
    this.hours=hours;
}

public double pay(){
    int otHours=0;
    if(hours>40){
        otHours=hours-40;
    }
    double pay=(hours-otHours)*payRate+(otHours*payRate*1.5);
    return pay;
}

public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "\nCurrent Hours: " +hours;
}
}


//Commission Class
public class Commission extends Hourly{
    private double totalSales, commissionRate;

public Commission(double commissionrate, String rsiNumber, double payRate, String name, String address, String number) {
    super(rsiNumber, payRate, name, address, number);
    this.commissionRate = commissionrate;
    this.totalSales=0;
}

public void addSales(int sales){
    this.totalSales=sales;
}

public double pay(){
    return super.pay()+(totalSales*commissionRate);
}

public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "\nTotal Sales: " +totalSales;
}
}


//Casting Method From Another Class
public void processStaff(){
    for(int i=0; i<sm.length; i++){
        if (sm[i] instanceof Hourly) {
            Hourly h = (Hourly) sm[i];
            if(h.name.equals("Joanne")){
                h.addHours(50);
            }
        }else if (sm[i] instanceof Executive) {
            Executive e = (Executive) sm[i];
            if(e.name.equals("John")){
                e.awardBonus(500);
            }
        }else if (sm[i] instanceof Commission) {
            Commission c = (Commission) sm[i];
            if(c.name.equals("Molly")){
                c.addHours(55);
                c.addSales(400);
            }else if(c.name.equals("Joe")){
                c.addHours(45);
                c.addSales(950);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get when I should be getting values returned and not 0.

[image]

Edit: Seem to have found the solution by just putting Commission inside of Hourly since Commission is a type of Hourly.

```
public void processStaff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sm.length; i++) {
        if (sm[i] instanceof Hourly) {
            Hourly h = (Hourly) sm[i];
            if (h.name.equals("Joanne")) {
                h.addHours(50);
            } else if (sm[i] instanceof Commission) {
                Commission c = (Commission) sm[i];
                if (c.name.equals("Molly")) {
                    c.addHours(55);
                    c.addSales(400);
                } else if (c.name.equals("Joe")) {
                    c.addHours(45);
                    c.addSales(950);
                }
            }
        } else if (sm[i] instanceof Executive) {
            Executive e = (Executive) sm[i];
            if (e.name.equals("John")) {
                e.awardBonus(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your staffmember class ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I added it now but its a pretty basic class so I didn't bother, the error isn't there.

Comment: thanks , you want to change the values of current hours and paid and total sales ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yes as you can see in the picture the last three are 0 for some reason and im not sure why

Comment: what's in the sm array ? send me your code :

adv.javax92@gmail.com

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi There is my project, there is a few classes but they're not long. https://github.com/Poena1/InheritenceProblem

Comment: I think you are missing `@Override` annotation on your `toString()` method.

Comment: @Ravikumar i don't think the problem will be with Override , because the toString method runs perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       if (sm[i] instanceof Hourly) {

       /* .... */
       }else if (sm[i] instanceof Commission) {
            Commission c = (Commission) sm[i];
            if(c.name.equals("Molly")){
                c.addHours(55);
                c.addSales(400);
            }else if(c.name.equals("Joe")){
                c.addHours(45);
                c.addSales(950);
            }
       }
```

The first condition is true for `Commission` so you never call addHours or addSales on it. Hence nothing to display.

You really should look at the content of the classes with a debugger.

Comment: I have an object of Hourly as well so what would I do? Have an inner if statement for commission? I'm fairly new to this side of java.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You can change the order of the if statements (Comission first) so only the Comission part is executed. You can remove the `else` so Hourly and Comission is executed.

Comment: it seems to be working now with the code I just updated my question with.

Comment: You should rethink your design man, doing some nesting instanceof's and invoking methods based on names (what if you had million people in the list?) is not a good idea. Also use getters and setters, always, never do something like `myObject.name`.

Comment: @Whatzs yeah I know, that'd make things a lot easier but it was just the schematics for a lab I had to do.